# Scala 2.10.4: when parsing this quasiquote, a exception throwed

Tags: scala-quasiquotes

```
        q"""
        val x = ${evalA.primitiveTerm}
        val y = ${evalB.primitiveTerm}
        val res = 0
        for (i <- 0 until x.length; if i < y.length) {
          val res = x(i).compareTo(y(i))
          if (res != 0) return res
        }
        return x.length - y.length
        """
```

When i execute the above code i am getting below error

```
Error:(49, 13) exception during macro expansion: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.end on class scala.reflect.internal.util.OffsetPosition
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Position.end(Position.scala:126)
    at scala.quasiquotes.TreeGen.closurePos$1(TreeGen.scala:670)
    at scala.quasiquotes.TreeGen.mkFor(TreeGen.scala:677)
    at scala.quasiquotes.TreeGen.mkFor(TreeGen.scala:682)
    at org.scalamacros.paradise.parser.Parsers$Parser.parseFor$1(Parsers.scala:1445)
```

Comment: This is ok under scala 2.11+, but my original project used scala 2.10.4

Comment: Are you sure `return` is required? (What is exactly your question? How to work around? What is the issue number in the Scala bug tracker? Is it fixed in 2.10.6? How to report a bug? ...?)